# How to add a leading 0 to the output of shuf if the result is a single digit?

Tags: bash, padding

Let's say I run this command:

```
shuf -i 0-12 -n 1
```

If the result is 0 - 9, I want the result changed to 00 - 09.

If the result is 10 - 12, leave the result as is.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: https://devhints.io/bash is a phenomenal reference for bash syntax.

Comment: `printf "%s\n" {00..12} | shuf -n 1`?

Comment: Great answer @Cyrus! Thanks

Comment: Another approach only with `bash`: `printf "%0.2d\n" $(($RANDOM%13))`

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the number is less than ten and modify it as a string, accordingly. If shuf returns a string & not an int, then you could check string length instead.  I think string length is `len=${num#}`, then you'd check if len is `-eq 1`

```
num=$(shuf ...)

if [[ $shuf -lt 10 ]]; then
    num="0${num}"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @Reed. Very simple. I was overthinking things.

Comment: Yw! That's easy to do with programming.